# determine the height of rectangle as function of x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

My textbook does not give an example of how to solve this problem so I'm not sure how to approach it. The problem asks, "Write the height h of the rectangle as a function of x." The back of the book gives the answer $h = -x^2 + 4x - 3$, which is a variation of the given function in the image, but I have no idea how to arrive at the answer. Any thoughts?

[image: function graph]

Comment: You have write the answer, but what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my post.

Comment: If we don't know something more about the rectangle and what $x$ is, we cannot help you !

Comment: The question is asking for the height of the rectangle in the diagram, which for a given value of $x$ in the interval, is the difference between the height of the parabola $y = -x^2 + 4x - 1$ and the line $y = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand the request of the problem.

It seems a simple problem: I would say that $h=(-x^2+4x-1)-2=-x^2+4x-3$ in fact $h$ represents the distance between the parabola of equation $y=-x^2+4x-1$ and the line y=2.

Maybe you've to find the equation of the parabola from the graph. In this case you should impose that points $(1,2)$ and $(3,2)$ belong to the curve and that $2=-b/2a$  (vertex condition).